# Is there an easy way to access Outlook contacts outside of VSTO?

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto

At work we use a couple of custom columns in the Outlook contacts to serve as an "signout board" so we can see when developers are at another site since we're spread out across a couple of locations. The way this is currently implemented is via a custom view of the contacts that is displayed as a spreadsheet that folks can update their status with.

I'd like to create a little tool that functions more like your typical IM client, where I can simply pick a status from a drop down, click it, and be done. No need to pull up the special contact list from my favorites or anything like that. This is also helpful since we'll update the status of another other developer in the event they call in sick.

I see how I can do this with VSTO as an add-in to Outlook, but I'd like to make it a standalone app. All the documentation I've looked through so far has been messy COM stuff or concerns regarding security issues.

Is there an easy way to access/update Outlook contacts outside of VSTO, or would I be better off simply sticking with creating an Add-In?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to taken a look at using Exchanage WebDav or EWS ? It pretty easy to write an app that will update your conatcts etc. or Take a look at redemption http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/ You can use the rdo object lib to build you app.

Comment: EWS was the way to go for me over here, but Redemption was a great looking library too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you call "easy". Using MAPI, you can access the Outlook contacts without any of the security issues or other hassle, but if you have no experience using the API the code itself might be a bit overwhelming.

One of the easiest ways to access MAPI from .net is using an old (free) version of [MAPI33](http://g8.cx/mapi/). The current commercial version seems to have gone belly-up.